# Is it possible to deduce template argument without explicit specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to do something to help the compiler deduce the template argument to avoid explicit specialization?

Code:

```
template<typename T, int>
struct S
{
};

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    template<int N>
    A(S<T, N>)
    {
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(A<T> arg)
{    
}
```

Call:

```
S<int, 10> s;
A<int> v = s;

foo<int>(s); //OK
foo(v); //OK
foo(s); // error C2784: 'void foo(A<T>)': could not deduce template argument for 'A<T>'
```

Comment: Nope, non-deducible context.

Comment: Specializing `foo` won't do you much good. You'd want to overload it.

Comment: `foo` accepts templates of `A`. Is `s` a template of `A`? This requires overloading, not specialization.

Answer (score 2):

You can accept any object convertible to `A<?>` and manually convert it inside the function.

#### If you have no other `foo()` overloads

...you can simply go for

```
void foo(auto t) {
  A arg{t}; // use this as you would've used "A<T> arg" in your example
}
```

For older C++ versions, bring the necessary amount of hacks from ones presented below.

#### If you need to choose among multiple template overloads

...and therefore need SFINAE, the solution is a bit more complicated:

```
void foo(auto t) requires requires { A{t}; } {
  A arg{t};
}
```

Without C++20, there's no `requires` (and `auto` function parameters). A workaround:

```
template<typename T> auto foo(T t) -> std::void_t<decltype(A{t})> {
  A arg{t};
}
```

If you can't even use C++17, you have no [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) => no `A{t}` (and no `std::void_t`; even though it's a one-liner, in the following example I'll show another old SFINAE trick just FYI). To hack it around, I'll suggest the same method that STL used - `make_` functions. For C++14 and even C++11:

```
template<typename T, int N> A<T> make_A(S<T, N> s) { return s; }
template<typename T> A<T> make_A(A<T> a) { return a; }

template<typename T> void foo(T t, decltype(make_A(t))* = nullptr) {
  auto arg = make_A(t);
}
```